# Error running default MVC 6 project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I was creating First MVC 6 Web Application , but on create only I'm getting error at References ( Error - see Error List ) as shown in [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x68zN.jpg). I have tried several times also refered many Blogs where giving ASP.NET 5 tutorial ( Stackoverflow, Codeproject, ASP.Net/vNext and many more ) I think there is some problem with my installed VS 2015 or might be some thing else, not getting were I'm making mistake

Comment: 1. Did you installed newest version of ASP.NET tooling for VS2015? 2. Did you installed DNX?

Comment: I have run following command in cmd 1)  dnvm upgrade 2) dnvm upgrade -r coreclr 3) dnvm upgrade -r clr . Then created project. Did I miss any thing ?

Answer (score 1):

On your Visual Studio Package Manager Console run the command

```
dnu restore
```

Answer (score 0):

While dnu restore usually helps, I have found that the way to make it run automatically is to turn on the checkboxes in Options->Nuget Package manager. If you turn the first two ones on, then it should be doing this automatically without the need to run the console all the time (at least it worked for me).

[image]

P.S. I don't know what kind of connection exists between these checkboxes and the dnu restore, but somehow it triggers restore.